# Sorting excel formula value (Dynamic) with same value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have data that has much same value. So I want to sort it by the value but also by alphabetical. This is the data :

[image: the data]

the value of 'information gain' was a formula. How can I sort it by value and also by alphabetical ascending (A - Z)?

Comment: what is your formula used in `information gain`? if you can please edit your post to include the formula. And if there is formula used for the first or second column, also post them out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope it's easy by following below steps.

Refer below as an example.

The B column as name is not in order as A-Z
and The C column values in formulas.

Select the Data => Then use The Short cut of **Alt + A + S + S**  to sort the table.
In first condition select the information Gain and the **order by** can be **Smallest to largest** or **largest to smallest** as per your requirement, and then B Column of **Kata** in second condition which order should be **A-Z**

[image]

**Here is the final result after using the above mentioned short cut option:**

[image]

Please let me know if it doesn't worked. So that will find for a new solution.

Comment: hey sir, thank you for your answer. I have tried this way but it seems it doesn't work.

Comment: the formula won't stay on the same row